# Remote Debugging tablet/mobile browser (No USB debugging)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, remote-debugging, tablet

How can I debug a tablet/mobile browser located remotely.

I checked few StackOverflow questions but could only get the option to debug a device after connecting it through USB cable to laptop/computer.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode supports remote debugging of iOS devices but you must first connect the device via usb to configure the remote debugging. Here is a [post](https://medium.com/aaronn/enable-wireless-builds-debug-in-xcode-9-ios-11-4f4293a184bc) on how to enable it.

Comment: Is there a way to debug without connecting the device to USB. As I have to debug my device located in a different city

Comment: This is not supported via Xcode, you must be connected to the same network for it to work. There might be some 3rd party software that allows this but unless you already have it installed, I don't think it is possible. You could theoretically have the user plug the device in to a computer and then do a remote session with that computer to debug it. You could probably understand that there would be security risks if it was allowed to do remote debugging in any other conditions.